# Keep DIV in Spot when DIV next to it Changes In Size

Tags: php, ajax, html

So I've got a div which is populated via AJAX, and when it changes size the div next to it moves down with the bottom edge of the div next to it. How do I get it so that the div on the right stays in place?

```
<div class="body">
        <div class="slection">
            <div class="selector">
                <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <option value="Select day...">Select day...</option>
                <?php
                $pathToMe = dirname(__FILE__);
                $path = $pathToMe . "/days/";
                $handle=opendir($path);
                    while ($file=readdir($handle))
                    {
                        if (($file == ".") || ($file == "..")){
                    }
                        else echo "\t<option value='".$file."'>".$file."</option>\n";
                    }
                ?>
                </select> 
          </div>
          <div id="content"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="sms">
            <div style="text-align:center">
                Send SMS to client
            </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
                <div id="contact_form">  
                    <form name="contact" action="">  
                      <fieldset>  
                        <input type="text" name="number" id="number" size="14" value="Number" class="text-input" />  
                      <br /><br />
                        <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" value="Message" class="text-input"></textarea>  


                        <br />  
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />  
                      </fieldset>  
                    </form>  
</div>  
</div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.header {
    height:30px;
}

.body {
    min-width:400px;
    max-width:700px;
    min-height:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:500px
}

.sms {
    float:right;
    margin-top:-20px;
}

.selection {
    float:left;

}
```

Live example [here](http://pkazz.com/scheduler/console.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
pre{
width:200px;
float:left;
}
```

to your CSS.

Currently the `pre` takes the width of the whole area. Defining it as 200px wide still won't bring the other element up to the same level as it is with isn't `display:inline;`, so that's why you need the `float` as well.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. I have to wait 10 mins to accept your answer. Why does that work exactly?